# Libvirt-go start domain

Tags: go, libvirt

When I defining new domain

```
_, err = v.conn.DomainDefineXMLFlags(domainXml, libvirt.DOMAIN_DEFINE_VALIDATE)
```

xml looks like:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
    <name>{{.name}}</name>
    <memory unit='KiB'>{{.memory}}</memory>
    <currentMemory unit='KiB'>{{.current_memory}}</currentMemory>
    <vcpu>{{.count_cpu}}</vcpu>
    <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-disco'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    </os>
    <clock offset='utc'/>
    <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
    <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
    <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
    <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
        <driver name='qemu' type='raw' cache='none'/>
        <source dev='{{.lvm_path}}'/>
        <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
        <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
        <source file='{{.config_file}}'/>
        <target dev='sda' bus='sata'/>
        <readonly/>
        <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='virbr0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <mac address='{{.mac_address}}'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    </devices>
</domain>
```

go-libvirt makes a new `persistent domain`.  But this domain is shutted down.

```
$ virsh list --all
 Id   Name         State
---------------------------
 -    new_domain   shut off
```

In source code https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go/blob/master/domain.go I didn't find solutions how can I run this domain with golang ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`Create`](https://godoc.org/github.com/libvirt/libvirt-go#Domain.Create) method on the `Domain` object that is returned from `DomainDefineXMLFlags`. For example

```
dom, err := v.conn.DomainDefineXMLFlags(domainXml, libvirt.DOMAIN_DEFINE_VALIDATE)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
err = dom.Create()
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```